# VLC - Cannot connect to UDP stream

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vlc

I try to connect to an existing UDP stream on `udp://IP:1234`, but this does not work on my Ubuntu 20.04, it just keeps loading. I know that the stream works because I've tested using a Windows VM.

Version: `VLC version 3.0.9.2 Vetinari`

Output:

```
[00007f9ab80015f0] udp stream debug: opening server=IP:1234 local=:1234
[00007f9ab80015f0] main stream debug: net: connecting to [IP]:1234 from []:1234
[00007f9ab80015f0] main stream debug: using access module "udp"
[00007f9ab80029a0] main stream debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "prefetch,cache_block": 26 candidates
[00007f9ab80029a0] prefetch stream debug: using 16777216 bytes buffer, 16777216 bytes
[00007f9ab80029a0] main stream debug: using stream_filter module
[00007f9ab8002e50] main stream debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "any": 26
[00007f9ab4000c20] main meta fetcher debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 1
[00007f9ab4000c20] lua meta fetcher debug: Trying Lua scripts in /home/ubuntu/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
[00007f9ab4000c20] lua meta fetcher debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
[00007f9ab4000c20] lua meta fetcher debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
[00007f9ab4000c20] main meta fetcher debug: no meta fetcher modules matched
[00007f9ab4000c20] main art finder debug: looking for art finder module matching "any": 2
[00007f9ab4000c20] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua scripts in /home/ubuntu/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/art
[00007f9ab4000c20] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art
[00007f9ab4000c20] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/00_musicbrainz.luac
[00007f9ab4000c20] lua art finder debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/00_musicbrainz.luac
[00007f9ab4000c20] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/01_googleimage.luac
[00007f9ab4000c20] lua art finder debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/01_googleimage.luac
[00007f9ab4000c20] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/02_frenchtv.luac
[00007f9ab4000c20] lua art finder debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/02_frenchtv.luac
[00007f9ab4000c20] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/03_lastfm.luac
[00007f9ab4000c20] lua art finder debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/03_lastfm.luac
[00007f9ab4000c20] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/art
[00007f9ab4000c20] main art finder debug: no art finder modules matched
```

Ref: [Cannot connect with UDP stream](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=154867)